# Delegate mocks to separate class

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

Instead of having this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

   @MockBean
   private FooAdapter fooAdapter;

   @MockBean
   private BarAdapter barAdapter;

   public void mockFoo() {
      FooResponse dto = new FooResponse();
      when(fooAdapter.fooRequest()).thenReturn(dto);
   }
```

I want to have that:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

   @MockBean/Autowired?
   MockProvider mockProvider;


class MockProvider {

   @MockBean
   private FooAdapter fooAdapter;

   @MockBean
   private BarAdapter barAdapter;

   public void mockFoo() {
      FooResponse dto = new FooResponse();
      when(fooAdapter.fooRequest()).thenReturn(dto);
   }
```

However, I don't know if that is even possible using Mockito with `SpringRunner`. Since we have a lot of adapters (like 10), I do not want to pollute the `AbstractIT` too much, hence I'd like to delegate the initialization and concrete mocking of those dependencies out to another class taking care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify that provider class in the `@ContextConfiguration` for each test you want to use it for:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockProvider.class}  // <-- this
public abstract class AbstractIT {
```

You have to make sure to make the provider a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MockProvider {
```

As per **@MockBean** documentation:

> The annotation can be used directly on test classes, on fields within
>   your test, or on @Configuration classes and fields.